Make a template for an article in a given custom taxonomy value with the block theme editor
I am building a block theme with full site editing.
I created a custom taxonomy "section" using ACF/SCF with one of the value being "event". I now want to create a custom template for all articles in the "event" value of the custom taxonomy. I used the template named "section : event" but it isn't used by my "event" posts.
After checking the template hierarchy, it seems -but I'm not sure- that this template is in fact the template for "event" archives. I did not find any template in the editor that fit what I want (articles what I want).
Is there such a template? Should I rather make my events a custom post type rather than putting it in a taxonomy ? Or do I have to use PHP directly in that case?
